# Adding extra days for each month in pandas

Tags: python, database, pandas

In a pandas df, I have number of days for a given month in the first col and Amount in the sec col. How can I add the days that are not in there for that month in the first col and give the value 0 for it in the second col

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({
'Date':['5/23/2019', '5/9/2019'],
'Amount':np.random.choice([10000])
})
```

I would like the result to look like the following:

Expected Output

```
       Date  Amount
 0  5/01/2019   0
 1  5/02/2019   0
 .
 .
 .  5/23/2019  1000
 .  5/24/2019   0
```

Comment: why don't you have `5/31/2019` in the output?

Comment: Is this example complete? What happens when you have more than 2 rows?

Comment: That was meant to give a part of the output to give an idea of what I was trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) from pandas.

I'm assuming that 5/31/2019 is not in your output like the comment asks because you want the differences between the min and max dates?

I convert the `date` column to a datetime type. I pass the min and max date to `date_range` and store that in a dataframe. then I do left join.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
date_range = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start=df['Date'].min(), end=df['Date'].max()), columns=['Date'])
final_df = pd.merge(date_range, df, how='left')

         Date   Amount
0  2019-05-09  10000.0
1  2019-05-10      NaN
2  2019-05-11      NaN
3  2019-05-12      NaN
4  2019-05-13      NaN
5  2019-05-14      NaN
6  2019-05-15      NaN
7  2019-05-16      NaN
8  2019-05-17      NaN
9  2019-05-18      NaN
10 2019-05-19      NaN
11 2019-05-20      NaN
12 2019-05-21      NaN
13 2019-05-22      NaN
14 2019-05-23  10000.0
```